# LIBGDX Camera doesn't move

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

My game sets this screen and I see the actor that I create.

However can anyone tell me why the camera doesn't seem to be moving? I would expect the actor to move to the right as I pressed the Left key.

The *Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)* does resolve to true and the translate function does get called.

```
public class MainScreen implements Screen {

    private Stage mainStage;
    private Camera orthCamera;

    @Override
    public void show() {


        orthCamera = new OrthographicCamera();

        mainStage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
        mainStage.getViewport().setCamera(orthCamera);

        MyGameActorObject s = new MyGameActorObject();
        s.setPosition(100, 100);

        mainStage.addActor(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1); //sets clear
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        processKeyboardInput();

        mainStage.act(delta);
        mainStage.draw();
    }

    private void processKeyboardInput()
    {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
            orthCamera.translate(-30, 0, 0);
            orthCamera.update();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        mainStage.dispose();
    }
}
```

I am trying to acheieve being able to pan around the 2d game world using keyboard input.

This is the contents of the custom Actor object:

```
public class MyGameActorObject extends Actor
{
    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

        ShapeRenderer r = new ShapeRenderer();

        r.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        r.setColor(Color.RED);
        r.circle(this.getX() - 50.0f, this.getY() - 50.0f, 100.0f);
        r.end();

    }
}
```

Comment: Does anything at all happen when you press the left key?

Comment: Does the `isKeyPressed` return true when you would expect it to?

Comment: Maybe try using the camera created internally by ScreenViewport ([example](https://gist.github.com/hexaglow/24148b949b2b1f2e960b))

Comment: Same results with that bit of code.

Comment: Does it have something to do with my game object? As when I use Image actor then it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have to add something like

```
r.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
```

in my custom actor object. So the draw function on my object would now be.

```
    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

        ShapeRenderer r = new ShapeRenderer();

        r.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
        r.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        r.setColor(Color.RED);
        r.circle(this.getX() - 50.0f, this.getY() - 50.0f, 100.0f);
        r.end();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you haven't set the `InputProcessor`.

`Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(...)` is the method you're looking for. Put it in your `show()` method and pass it an `InputProcessor` reference. InputProcessor is an interface that goes through all the different types of click-based input and allows you to determine what happens in them. So for instance:

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode)
{
    switch(keycode)
    {
        case Keys.D:
            screen.universe.entity_handler.player.moving_right = true;
            break;
        case Keys.A:
            screen.universe.entity_handler.player.moving_left = true;
            break;
        case Keys.SPACE:
            screen.universe.entity_handler.player.jumping = true;
            break;
        ...
   }
   ...
}
```

The above code is part of an `InputProcessor`-implementing class for a game I'm making. When the input in-question is pressed (`keyDown` in this case), the game looks at your input button (the `keycode`) and sends it through the switch statement.

Keep in mind that you must return `true` for all the input events that you want to use. That's what the `boolean` return value for this method is.

Comment: The isKeyPressed event does fire though, and from what I can see the camera does get translated. Im not using an event listener, I am checking the state instead.

Comment: The advice is solid, but the OP wasn't using the InputProcessor API - they're using `isKeyPressed`, which should work fine on its own.